# Figure not showing in static frame (flowfram package)

Tags: graphics, flowfram

I am trying to reproduce the layout for a pdf document with three columns and several images that span two columns (that need to appear at a specific place). Therefore, I am using the package flowfram, with staticcontents environments for the images.

The problem is that one of the images is not appearing. The others appear as intended. Earlier, the one with the problem did appear as well, but at some point it no longer did, and I can't work out why. If I change the newstaticframe definition such that the image would show up on the second page rather than the first page, it does show (partially behind the other images that get drawn on top of it, obviously).

I am using Windows 10 and TeXworks. I checked the log file and it talks about underfull hboxes, but it does that for all images, and the others do show. I can't find anything else that suggests what the issue might be.

I tried to remove as much from the document as possible to create this MWE—I hope it is indeed sufficiently minimal. The times package did not seem to be relevant, but when I tried to remove it for the MWE, the other images didn't show up anymore either, and the text shifted somewhat and created a third page—no idea what was going on there either.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english,latin]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{times}


\newflowframe[1]{0.30\textwidth}{\textheight}
{0pt}{0pt}[leftcolumn]

\newflowframe[1]{0.30\textwidth}{0.50\textheight}
{0.35\textwidth}{0pt}[shortcentercolumn]

\newflowframe[1]{0.30\textwidth}{0.50\textheight}
{0.7\textwidth}{0pt}[shortrightcolumn]

\newflowframe[2]{0.30\textwidth}{0.38\textheight}
{0pt}{0.62\textheight}[supershortleftcolumn]

\newflowframe[2]{0.30\textwidth}{0.38\textheight}
{0.35\textwidth}{0.62\textheight}[supershortcentercolumn]

\newstaticframe[1]{0.65\textwidth}{0.50\textheight}
{0.35\textwidth}{.5\textheight}[statico]

\newstaticframe[2]{0.65\textwidth}{0.60\textheight}
{0pt}{0pt}[statico2]

\newstaticframe[2]{0.35\textwidth}{0.90\textheight}
{0.67\textwidth}{0.05\textheight}[rightstatic]


\begin{document}


\noindent\textbf{\textsc{the James Joyce museum,}}\\
\textbf{Joyce Tower, Sandycove, Co. Dublin}

\noindent\lipsum[1-7]

\begin{staticcontents*}{statico}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.48\textheight]{museum}\\
\end{staticcontents*}

\begin{staticcontents*}{statico2}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.58\textheight]{outside}\\
\end{staticcontents*}

\begin{staticcontents*}{rightstatic}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.95\textheight]{logo}\\
\captionof{figure}
{\small Lorem ipsum}
\end{staticcontents*}


\end{document}
```

This is how the pages appear for me:
[image: page 1]
[image: page 2]

As mentioned, if I change the static frame to apply to page 2 rather than 1, the image does show:

```
\newstaticframe[2]{0.65\textwidth}{0.50\textheight}
{0.35\textwidth}{.5\textheight}[statico]
```

[image: page 2 with image]

Does anybody know why the image is not showing? Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: You need to set the static frame contents before the page starts.

Comment: Terrific, that solved it! I placed the staticcontents* environment immediately after \begin{document} and now the image shows as intended. Such a simple thing... thank you very much.

Comment: Glad it works now. I've added a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of the frames are added to the current page in the following order (excluding any that aren't visible for that page):

1. static frames;
2. flow frames (that is, normal document text);
3. dynamic frames.

This means that the static frames must be set before the start of the page on which they appear. If they are set while the flow frames are being filled by the document text for that page, then it's too late for the static contents to appear on the current page.